# Append child not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild

CSS:

```
ul #allposts li{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id = "allposts"></ul>
```

JS:

```
var woow2 = document.getElementById('allposts');
var oneofpost = document.createElement('li');
woow2.appendChild(oneofpost);
```

When I run the code, the oneofpost does not appear. It should appear as a little yellow brick right?

Any ideas why?

Comment: this works when used in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @user3122407 Doesn't work as it was supposed to. CSS selector was the problem.

Comment: @manta ["Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "](http://jsbin.com/OfOSIsEN/1)

Comment: Tip: Avoid css IDs if they aren't needed at all. They make the item _very_ specific. It will be a trouble to edit :P

Comment: sorry bud, this is `jquery`, `javascript` code is like so: `window.onload=function(){somecodehere};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS. Your selector should be:

```css
ul#allposts li
```

But IDs should be unique, so you shouldn't need to qualify it with a tag name:

```css
#allposts li
```

Your selector as it currently stands reads:

All `li` elements that are descendants of elements with the ID of `allposts` that are descendants of all `ul` elements, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/dFD7p/

```
#allposts li{  //just removed the ul(space) and works
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the space between `ul` and `#allposts`.
That should do it.

(Note: you actually don't need `ul#allposts` because IDs are unique as other answers have reminded me.)